# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s: iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, audio, xcode5.1

I need to convert my audio files in to PCM and i am using iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest sample project for that. I have copied and pasted all the files from that project to my project which i have need. 
Changed the extensions of .cpp to .mm. verified that all the frameworks are in there. but still i am getting this error. I have searched a lot but could not find anything except which i have written above.

Here is the error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_DoConvertFile", referenced from:
      -[EditViewController convertAudio:DestPath:] in EditViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue as you facing, then i did this,

Created interface file and library of iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest project and used in another project, where i needed to convert mp3 file to PCM. Hope that helps you

Comment: Hi @Sandeep, Thank you for your reply, Can you please explain some more?. What that interface file will do? I just needed to convert my songs audio files into PCM.

Comment: Create a   .h file, include the methods that you call from the place where you want to convert audio to PCM.
and .m file corresponding to .h file will be part of static library.
use the .h file to interact with library.